# chown not working

Tags: command-line, permissions, chown, ownership

I am trying to take ownership of a directory recursively.

```
sudo chown -R themes/
```

But I am getting the error:

```
user@linux-main:/usr/share$ sudo chown -R themes/
chown: missing operand after ‘themes/’
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First you need to be VERY CAREFUL using a recursive command using sudo and -R, and second, you need to use the correct format for the command. See `man chown` for help. Lastly, exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited one of my numix theme files and corrupted it. I want to replace the whole folder / individual files. I thought it would be easier to just own the themse folder. In addition I want to install new themes easily. EDIT: I fixed the theme the proper way using apt-get, so I didn't need this command anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command should be:

```
sudo chown -R $USER themes/
```

You are missing the `username` part that you intend to own the directory. The `$USER` refers to your `username` which can and should be substituted into that command.

Comment: Careful there; can usernames contain spaces?

Comment: Spaces, don't follow?

Comment: What happens if I run your command and `$USER` contains a space?

Comment: @fkraiem now how does one create a `username` with space, would this run `sudo adduser har t`?